# init.js Obect expected error with SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Tags: javascript, custom-list, client-object-model

I am using  SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded as follows

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(itemid), "sp.js");
```

Yet I am getting an error object expected error. I read that it's something to do with the (`itemid`) but when I need to pass that into the method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName);
```

Parameters:
func - The function to execute.
Type: Function

depScriptFileName - The name of the file containing the function.
Type: String

The `func` parameter is the function-object, not some JavaScript code. You can create parameterless function and call in it your `NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(itemid)`

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(someSimpleWrapper, "sp.js");
function someSimpleWrapper(){
  NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(itemid);
}
```